# Stream to array convertor without slurp

Tags: json, jq

My JSON input:

```
  {  "Key": "Team",     "Value": "AA" }
  {  "Key": "Division", "Value": "BB" }
```

Desired output:

```
[
  {  "Key": "Team",     "Value": "AA" },
  {  "Key": "Division", "Value": "BB" }
]
```

I cannot use the `--slurp` option because I'm in a middle of complex jq code.

The mentioned input is a result of my function and I need to convert it to an array for further processing.

The solution recommended in FAQ: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#general-questions

```
cat json | jq 'reduce . as $i ([]; . + [$i])'
```

produces something different:

```
[
  {  "Key": "Team",     "Value": "AA" }
]
[
  {  "Key": "Division", "Value": "BB" }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your input really is irredeemably a stream, and if you cannot use the slurp option, then the simplest would probably be to use jq 1.5's `inputs` filter, along the lines of:

`jq -n '[inputs]'`

If you don't use the -n option, then the first JSON entity won't be seen by `inputs`.  If you cannot use the -n option, then use `[., inputs]`

Comment: cat json | jq -n '[inputs]'  has exactly same limitation as cat json | jq -s '.'.

Comment: Seriously? the OP says they can't use -s because they are already in the middle of a calculation and you suggest -n?

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need is to use the jq array constructor syntax.  I.e. enclose whatever complex expression you have that generates the stream in a pair of `[ ]`

Here is an example.  For the sake of argument I'll use a function in place of whatever complex expression you have.  e.g.

```
def some_complex_expression:
  {  "Key": "Team",     "Value": "AA" },
  {  "Key": "Division", "Value": "BB" }
;
```

If we just execute this expression

```
some_complex_expression
```

the result is a stream of two objects as we expect:

```
{
  "Key": "Team",
  "Value": "AA"
}
{
  "Key": "Division",
  "Value": "BB"
}
```

But if we enclose the expression in `[ ]`

```
[ some_complex_expression ]
```

the result is a single array containing the objects from the stream

```
[
  {
    "Key": "Team",
    "Value": "AA"
  },
  {
    "Key": "Division",
    "Value": "BB"
  }
]
```

Comment: This doesn't work on the input stream (the "--slurp" case): `echo '{"foo": "bar"}{"baz": "qux"}' | jq -r '[.]'` -> `[{"foo": "bar"}][{"baz": "qux"}]`. @peak's answer is correct: `[., inputs]` correctly gives `[{"foo": "bar"}, {"baz": "qux"}]`.